# Outlook Hangs when running Firebird SQL Statement in Delphi application

Tags: delphi, firebird, outlook-redemption

I have an app written in Delphi 7, which using Firebird 2.1 db and connects to Outlook via redemption. 
when I run a slow query, which took 60-90 seconds,  in my app the outlook gets hang.

Can you guys tell me, why this happening and how can I fix it.

Thanks and regards,
Vijesh Nair

Comment: This probably has little to do with Firebird and allot to do with what you're doing with Outlook. Sooo, what are you doing in Outlook while executing your Firebird query? Can't the Query be done before you do what you need to do in Outlook? Can you show the Outlook code?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Let me explain, what I am doing. We have a SQL window in my app and started a SQL to execute, Then I switched to Outlook, When I selects any mail in Outlook window, didn't get selects until the SQL finishes its operation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand: You can't select something in Outlook until your SQL query is done? You click in Outlook and nothing happens? Or are you selecting something else in Outlook but the change is not reflected in your application until the query is finished?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I unable to use Outlook until I finish SQL processing

Comment: Can you run any other program when your query is processing? What does the task manager show regarding CPU use?

Comment: What is Redemption? [googles it] ... Oh I see.  Are you sure this isn't just an aspect of how Redemption works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your process puts a lock on the Outlook store (pst or mapi). There is not much you can do about that without changing your code so that it only opens the store when required.

Comment: you are right, may I need to move the functionality to a thread.

Comment: @VijeshV.Nair I don't think a thread will help. If your process puts  a lock on the Outlook store, then it is locked. Being the process threaded or not, the locking will block Outlook.